# Is there a way to solve the Interpreter Busy problem when using a custom Model in flutter while using Tflite Package?

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am developing a ML based Flutter Application in which I am using a custom model. Since the size of the custom model is >40MB I am not able to use Firebase hence I am integrating the model with the application. Since I am integrating it I am using the flutter package Tflite v1.1.1. When I am deploying my app for testing I am Getting an Error as This:

```
E/flutter (15794): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui dart state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception:PlatformException(Failed to run model, Interpreter busy, java.lang.RuntimeException::Interpreter busy.
E/flutter (15794): at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.<init>(TflitePlugin3 java:427)
E/flutter (15794): at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$RunModelOnImage.<init> (TflitePlugin.java:465)
E/flutter (15794): at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.onMethodCall(TflitePlugin java:102)
```

How can I solve this Issue? Please Help.

Code for my classify Images File:

```html
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';

loadModel() async {
  Tflite.close();
  await Tflite.loadModel(
      model: "assets/anifinder_model.tflite", labels: "assets/labels.txt");
}

void runModel(File image) async {
  var output = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
      path: image.path, numResults: 10, threshold: 0.5, asynch: true);

  print(output);
  close();
}

void close() {
  Tflite.close();
  print('Closed');
}
```

App HomePage Code:

```js
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:anifinder/constants.dart';
import 'package:anifinder/modelfunctions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  File _image = File('');

  Future<void> pickCropImage(ImageSource imgSource) async {
    final pickedImage = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: imgSource);

    final croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
      sourcePath: pickedImage!.path,
      androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
        backgroundColor: kackgroundcolor,
        toolbarColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
        toolbarTitle: 'Edit Image',
        toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.orange.shade600,
        lockAspectRatio: false,
      ),
    );
    setState(() {
      _image = File(croppedImage!.path);
    });
    runModel(_image);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadModel().then((value) => print('Model Loaded'));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            'AniFinder',
            style: headerStyle,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Select Image From Gallery'),
              style: kuttonStyle,
              onPressed: () {
                pickCropImage(ImageSource.gallery);
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40.0,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Click Image From Camera'),
              style: kuttonStyle,
              onPressed: () {
                pickCropImage(ImageSource.camera);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: kackgroundcolor,
    );
  }
}
```

When I run this app the Interpreter is not allowing the model to run. Please help me solve this Issue.
Version of Packages used:

1. cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
2. image_picker: ^0.7.4
3. image_cropper: ^1.4.0
4. image: ^2.1.4
5. tflite: ^1.1.1